# I can't seem to parent my mesh into my armature without it breaking and not move properly

Tags: rigging, armature

I'm trying to rig a character model. For some reason my mesh just breaks or not work properly when I parent it with an armature. This is before.

[image]

And this is after.

[image]

The clothes won't move with the arm and everything just don't work.

Comment: When you parent the mesh to the armature, which option are you picking from the Parent menu?

Comment: Hello, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/